Export "Total" row into excel from ag-grid
I have data in below format in ag-grid and when I try to export to excel all the rows got exported except "Total" row.
product category price1 price2 price3
apple   fruit1    3       4     5
apple   fruit2    6       8     5
carrot  veg1      5       6     9
carrot  veg2      58      25    60
Total             72      43    79


The above data has been grouped by columns on product and category.
I know this is limitation in ag-grid and should be using processRowGroupCallback to include this data. I am not able to achieve this and need some clear examples of how we can achieve this.
This is what I have tried so far:
const excel_sheet_name = fileName;
  const excel_params = {
        fileName: `${fileName}.xlsx`,
        sheetName: excel_sheet_name,
        processRowGroupCallback: function (params) {
          // Check if the row group is a "Total" row
          if (params.node.group && params.node.key === "Total") {
              // Clone the node's data
              var clonedData = Object.assign({}, params.node.data);
              // Remove the 'group' key from the cloned data
              delete clonedData["group"];
              // Return the modified data
              return clonedData;
          }
          // Return null for regular groups or leaf nodes
          return null;
      }
  };

  const onExportClick2 = useCallback(() => {
    gridRef.current.api.exportDataAsExcel(excel_params);
  }, [excel_params]);


To include the "Total" row when exporting data from ag-Grid to Excel, you can indeed utilize the processRowGroupCallback function. This function allows you to manipulate the data before it gets exported. Here's how you can achieve it:
    // Define your ag-Grid options
var gridOptions = {
    // Other options...
    processRowGroupCallback: function (params) {
        // Check if the row group is a "Total" row
        if (params.node.group && params.node.key === "Total") {
            // Clone the node's data
            var clonedData = Object.assign({}, params.node.data);
            // Remove the 'group' key from the cloned data
            delete clonedData["group"];
            // Return the modified data
            return clonedData;
        }
        // Return null for regular groups or leaf nodes
        return null;
    }
    // Other options...
};


Thanks for the responding, I have tried but no luck. Please check my post there I have updated what I have tried so far that includes your latest post.
